# How to handle Typo errors in postgres FullText search

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

I want to search for some text using full text search in postgres
here is an example of my query

```
select name, artist, texte
from testsearch
where to_tsvector(texte) @@ to_tsquery('randomname');
```

it gives me only results matching exactly 'randomname' , I want it to match also 'ran' ,'rand' radom' etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select name, artist, texte
from testsearch
where to_tsvector(texte) @@ to_tsquery('rand:*');
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
select name, artist AND texte
from testsearch near texte
where to_tsvector(texte) @@ to_tsquery('randomname');
```